# VS2010 Macro/Environment issue causing a HResult: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG) exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have looked at other posts and nothing worked or nothing I could do from my control.

VS 2010 Macro
Line of code that fails:
DTE.ExecuteCommand("ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Item.Deploy")

Error The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HResult: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in VBAssembly but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

I have tried deleting .vs folders and cache folders and suo files but nothing working to date.

Cannot reinstall or repair no install s\w.
I also have VS2019 on this laptop.
My solution is BI so whole bunch of SSRS projects if that matters.

Any suggestions please to try.